# Best approach to list all images from a specific directory and send to renderer process using Electron

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance, electron

I have a function in the main process that read all images that are in a directory and send it to the renderer process as a `base64string`. I have around 20 images each one with 15kb approximately however it is taking a lot to load them all (6seconds~7seconds) I wonder what are the best approaches to read multiple images and send to the renderer process.

The following code promisify the `readFile` method from node's `fs`.

```js
const readFromFile = (filePath) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fs.readFile(filePath, (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        reject(err);
      } else {
        resolve(data.toString("base64"));
      }
    });
  });
};
```

and then I wait till all images are read to send it back to the renderer process after adding the images to an `array` of `objects`.

```js
return Promise.all(videoThumbPromises.concat(dataThumbPromises)).then(
    (result) => {
      let amountOfImages = dataThumbPromises.length;
      for (let i = 0; i < dataThumbPromises.length; i++) {
        readyToUploadClips[i].thumbnail_video = result[i];
        readyToUploadClips[i].thumbnail_data = result[i + amountOfImages];
      }
      return readyToUploadClips;
    }
  );
```

The `videoThumbPromises` and `dataThumbPromises` are `arrays` of Promises generated by the `readFromFile` function.

Edit1: added preload.js script

```js
const { contextBridge, ipcRenderer } = require("electron");

const validateIPC = (channel) => {
  if (!channel || !channel.startsWith("recorder:")) {
    return false;
  }

  return true;
};

const globals = {
  ipcRenderer: {
    on(channel, listener) {
      if (!validateIPC(channel)) return;
      ipcRenderer.on(channel, (evt, message) => {
        listener(evt, message);
      });
    },
    removeListener(channel, listener) {
      if (!validateIPC(channel)) return;
      ipcRenderer.removeListener(channel, (evt, message) => {
        listener(evt, message);
      });
    },
    invoke(channel, data) {
      if (!validateIPC(channel)) return;
      return ipcRenderer.invoke(channel, data);
    },
  },
};

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld("electron", {
  globals,
});
```

Comment: Instead of sending the images data via IPC, how about you only send the image paths via IPC and have the render display them like browsers do best?

Comment: @midnight-coding I'm getting an error when trying to send only the image path: "Not allowed to load local resource". then I saw some threads about the error but they've said to disable de webSecurity flag isn't it a not very good solution tho? https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/23757

Comment: Are you able to add to your question your `preload.js` script?

Comment: @mid Yes i can do it

Comment: Your `preload.js` file looks fine. I think sending the image data via IPC is the wrong approach. I would only send an array of (string) absolute image paths via IPC to the render process. Within your html Javascript file, you would iterate over the array displaying each image like so: `<img src="file://C:\Users\Fred Flintstone\Pictures\Image 1.jpg" alt="Image 1">`. The path could be built within the main process before being sent to the render process. That way, your IPC call will only be milliseconds and Chromium is responsible for displaying the image(s) naturally. What do you think?

Comment: @midnight-coding Thanks for the quick response, I think this is the way to go! I already changed the logic to send the paths and it is working fine I had to set the webSecurity flag to false though (in development environment at least), I think the performance issue is caused due to the logic I have before reading the images and sending it to the renderer process because it is still slow. Btw, are you on electron's official discord channel? thank you

Comment: Yes, I am. Discord user name is `CustomDevTools#6728`. Feel free to add me to your friends list. Just about finished testing at my end as well. I'll post it for comparison when finished.

Answer (score 1):

Moving image data via IPC would be very resource intensive and costly in time. May I suggest only transporting the images (absolute) paths via IPC and have Chromium take care of the rest.

Below is a quick snippet of code to show how it could be done.

> Note: Error checking and image only filtering would need to be applied to the below code.

---

`preload.js` (main process)

```js
// Import the necessary Electron components.
const contextBridge = require('electron').contextBridge;
const ipcRenderer = require('electron').ipcRenderer;

// White-listed channels.
const ipc = {
    'render': {
        // From render to main.
        'send': [],
        // From main to render.
        'receive': [],
        // From render to main and back again.
        'sendReceive': [
            'dialog:openDirectorySelect' // Channel name
        ]
    }
};

// Exposed protected methods in the render process.
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld(
    // Allowed 'ipcRenderer' methods.
    'ipcRender', {
        // From render to main.
        send: (channel, args) => {
            let validChannels = ipc.render.send;
            if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
                ipcRenderer.send(channel, args);
            }
        },
        // From main to render.
        receive: (channel, listener) => {
            let validChannels = ipc.render.receive;
            if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
                // Deliberately strip event as it includes `sender`.
                ipcRenderer.on(channel, (event, ...args) => listener(...args));
            }
        },
        // From render to main and back again.
        invoke: (channel, args) => {
            let validChannels = ipc.render.sendReceive;
            if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
                return ipcRenderer.invoke(channel, args);
            }
        }
    }
);
```

---

`main.js` (main process)

```js
const electronApp = require('electron').app;
const electronBrowserWindow = require('electron').BrowserWindow;
const electronDialog = require('electron').dialog;
const electronIpcMain = require('electron').ipcMain;

const nodeFs = require("fs");
const nodePath = require("path");

// Prevent garbage collection
let window;

function createWindow() {
    const window = new electronBrowserWindow({
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        show: false,
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: false,
            contextIsolation: true,
            preload: nodePath.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
        }
    });

    window.loadFile('index.html')
        .then(() => { window.show(); });

    return window;
}

electronApp.on('ready', () => {
    window = createWindow();
});

electronApp.on('window-all-closed', () => {
    if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
        electronApp.quit();
    }
});

electronApp.on('activate', () => {
    if (electronBrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
        createWindow();
    }
});

// ---

function absoluteImagePaths(parentPath) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        nodeFs.readdir(parentPath, (error, files) => {
            if (error) {
                console.log('reject: ' + error); // Testing
                reject(error);
            } else {
                let result = [];

                files.forEach((file) => {
                    result.push('file://' + parentPath + nodePath.sep + file);
                });

                resolve(result);
            }
        });
    })
}

electronIpcMain.handle('dialog:openDirectorySelect', () => {
    let options = {
        title: 'Select Directory Containing Images',
        properties: ['openDirectory']
    };

    return electronDialog.showOpenDialog(window, options)
        .then((result) => {
            // Bail early if user cancelled dialog
            if (result.canceled) { return }

            return absoluteImagePaths(result.filePaths[0]);
        })
})
```

---

`index.html` (render process)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Electron Test</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <input type="button" id="button" value="Show Images From Folder">

        <ul id="images"></ul>
    </body>

    <script>
        document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
            window.ipcRender.invoke('dialog:openDirectorySelect')
                .then((paths) => {
                    if (paths === undefined) { return } // Dialog was cancelled

                    let result = '';

                    console.log(result);

                    for (let path of paths) {
                        result += `<img src="${path}"></img>`;
                    }

                    document.getElementById('images').innerHTML = result;
                })
        })
    </script>
</html>
```