# Loading local resources in an Electron App with a React frontend

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron

I am working on an Electron App with a React front end that is aimed at performing some  video tasks. At the moment, I am loading a video file on the backend, converting that to a base64 data format and then sending that to the React front end to use that as the source for the video player. This works as intended.

While this works great for smaller video files, there is a limit on how large the data being sent can be.

I was wondering if there's an actual way to let React load the media file directly by passing the local url as the source? I know this is disallowed for web security reasons but my app is wrapped inside Electron and does not connect to the Internet.

If that is not possible, alternatively, what would be the best way to load large media files (sizes of 4GB and etc ..) to view it in the player?

Importing the video file directly inside the React Component is not an option because the video is dynamically imported by the user by selecting it from the local system.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your question has the same basic problem as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72189472/best-approach-to-list-all-images-from-a-specific-directory-and-send-to-renderer). Instead, convert your video file(s) to base64 in your main thread and save it with a **new** filename. Then pass the full path of the new file (via [IPC](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/ipc)) to your render process for your render to use.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: That does not address the question. The issue is that even while setting an absolute path, React will refuse to load local resources. I've tried to use the protocol module in Electron to dispatch a custom protocol but that doesn't get recognized by React. The only way the video data actually seems to be accepted in React is either through the createObjectURL or a base64 encode.

I'm trying to find ways where I can avoid using either and actually allow React to directly import the local file by taking the absolute path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to find the solution to this. It is stated incorrectly in most places. So I decided to update what works for anyone else looking for an answer.

#### Do not disable webSecurity

Do **NOT** disable `webSecurity` as many places suggest. It is important to leave this on. If you **have to** do it, then you can set its value to `webSecurity: app.isPackaged`. This way during development it will be turned off but in a production build, it will be turned on. And because the app is being deployed from a file in the production build, local media works as intended.

But here's the actual fix with `webSecurity` still enabled.

## Solution

You need to create a [custom protocol](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/protocol) to handle your media. I had tried this many times before but unfortunately the code on the official docs for some reason does not return the values. So copying that directly just does not work.

```
app.whenReady().then(() => {
  // Create custom protocol for local media loading
  protocol.registerFileProtocol("media-loader", (request, callback) => {
    const url = request.url.replace("media-loader://", "");
    try {
      return callback(url);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(error);
      return callback(404);
    }
  });

  // Create Window
  createWindow();
});
```

Once you have this new protocol setup, it is just a matter of loading your media directly using their **absolute paths**.

```
<video src={`media-loader://${path}`}></video>
```

With this setup, you no longer need to create an ObjectURL or pass the media files over IPC which is just not performant has a size limitation on how large a file you can load.

Comment: This solution from @blessedcoder worked for me when trying to load a local video into an Electron app (using nextron) and ReactPlayer